# Two (different) BW numbers in fio output!

Tags: linux, io

fio output shows two bandwidth numbers at two places (for both read and write). What does these two numbers indicate? Which one should be considered for throughput test and for what the other one should be considered?

```
  1 {JOB}:{1}_{4k}_{5}: (g=0): rw=randrw, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodep    th=32
  2 ...
  3 fio-3.1
  4 Starting 16 threads
  5
  6 {JOB}:{1}_{4k}_{5}: (groupid=0, jobs=16): err= 0: pid=143919: Thu Oct 10 18:35:14 2019
  7    read: IOPS=50.1k, BW=196MiB/s (205MB/s)(34.4GiB/180002msec)
  8     slat (nsec): min=1210, max=191233, avg=3335.76, stdev=1810.98
  9     clat (usec): min=166, max=16660, avg=695.21, stdev=319.44
 10      lat (usec): min=169, max=16662, avg=698.62, stdev=319.39
 11     clat percentiles (usec):
 12      |  1.00th=[  338],  5.00th=[  396], 10.00th=[  433], 20.00th=[  482],
 13      | 30.00th=[  515], 40.00th=[  537], 50.00th=[  570], 60.00th=[  685],
 14      | 70.00th=[  832], 80.00th=[  914], 90.00th=[ 1012], 95.00th=[ 1188],
 15      | 99.00th=[ 1532], 99.50th=[ 2057], 99.90th=[ 3490], 99.95th=[ 3884],
 16      | 99.99th=[ 5997]
 17    bw (  KiB/s): min= 5883, max=16873, per=6.26%, avg=12545.77, stdev=3041.02, samples=5760
 18    iops        : min= 1470, max= 4218, avg=3136.15, stdev=760.26, samples=5760
 19   write: IOPS=952k, BW=3720MiB/s (3901MB/s)(654GiB/180002msec)
 20     slat (nsec): min=1192, max=927014, avg=3640.66, stdev=1926.60
 21     clat (usec): min=98, max=10023, avg=496.01, stdev=170.79
 22      lat (usec): min=100, max=10025, avg=499.72, stdev=170.69
 23     clat percentiles (usec):
 24      |  1.00th=[  273],  5.00th=[  326], 10.00th=[  355], 20.00th=[  388],
 25      | 30.00th=[  420], 40.00th=[  445], 50.00th=[  457], 60.00th=[  474],
 26      | 70.00th=[  486], 80.00th=[  510], 90.00th=[  865], 95.00th=[  930],
 27      | 99.00th=[ 1004], 99.50th=[ 1029], 99.90th=[ 1188], 99.95th=[ 1287],
 28      | 99.99th=[ 1467]
 29    bw (  KiB/s): min=121170, max=307136, per=6.26%, avg=238474.82, stdev=57541.32, samples=5760
 30    iops        : min=30292, max=76784, avg=59618.41, stdev=14385.36, samples=5760
 31   lat (usec)   : 100=0.01%, 250=0.25%, 500=73.65%, 750=12.84%, 1000=11.71%
 32   lat (msec)   : 2=1.52%, 4=0.02%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%
 33   cpu          : usr=6.39%, sys=33.77%, ctx=40608436, majf=0, minf=11562
 34   IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
 35      submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
 36      complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
 37      issued rwt: total=9019565,171442027,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
 38      latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32
 39
 40 Run status group 0 (all jobs):
 41    READ: bw=196MiB/s (205MB/s), 196MiB/s-196MiB/s (205MB/s-205MB/s), io=34.4GiB (36.9GB), run=180002-180002msec
 42   WRITE: bw=3720MiB/s (3901MB/s), 3720MiB/s-3720MiB/s (3901MB/s-3901MB/s), io=654GiB (702GB), run=180002-180002mse    c
 43
 44 Disk stats (read/write):
 45   nvme1n1: ios=9013394/171326957, merge=0/0, ticks=6201303/82738341, in_queue=103287914, util=100.00%
```

For example, for read, following are the relevant lines

```
7:   read: IOPS=50.1k, BW=196MiB/s (205MB/s)(34.4GiB/180002msec)
17:   bw (  KiB/s): min= 5883, max=16873, per=6.26%, avg=12545.77, stdev=3041.02, samples=5760
41:   READ: bw=196MiB/s (205MB/s), 196MiB/s-196MiB/s (205MB/s-205MB/s), io=34.4GiB (36.9GB), run=180002-180002msec
```

What does the "BW" in line 7 tells and what does the "bw" in line 17 tells? How are they different? For throughput test, which one should be considered?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, can you accept the one you deem best?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the ["Interpreting the output" section of the fio documentation](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#interpreting-the-output):

> **read/write/trim**
>
> [...] BW is the average bandwidth rate shown as: value in power of 2 format (value in power of 10 format).
>
> [...]
>
> **bw**
>
> Bandwidth statistics based on samples

One (BW) is `total I/O / time` the other (bw) is calculated by averaging samples collected at some set period while the job is running (notice `samples=5760` at the end of the line). Sample data can look VERY weird if you are running multiple jobs at the same time due to a bug in older version of fio (you may get a more sensible looking result with a more recent fio - see https://github.com/axboe/fio/releases for the latest release).

> Which one should be considered for throughput test and for what the other one should be considered?

BW is what you generally want to look at but the sampled statistics of bw (e.g. max, min, stdev) can be a strong warning sign that something is very wrong (but see the caveat above with older fio versions).

Answer (score 0):

I think a somewhat more comprehensive answer is given by Sitsofe Wheeler at https://www.spinics.net/lists/fio/msg05517.html where they write:

> BW is an average per second. bw is an average of averages...
>
> BW is calculated by summing all the I/O you did (1189MiB) and dividing
> by time in seconds so `(1189*1024.0)/(13001/1000.0)/1024 ~ 91.5`
>
> bw is calculated by summing all the "values" in the bw log and
> dividing by the number of those values. Each value is itself some sort
> of average but you don't know what period it is over. This can lead to
> a big discrepancy.
>
> Imagine I have a job that run for two seconds. In the first second 10
> MBytes is done over two I/Os. In the second second 100MByte is done
> over two I/Os. BW will be `120 / 2 = 60MBytes/s`. However imagine the bw
> values are like this
>
> ```
> 0. 10240, 0, 0
> 0, 10240, 0, 1024
> 1, 102400, 0, 2048
> 1, 102400, 0, 3072
>
> (10240 * 2 + 102400 * 2)/4.0/1024.0 = 55.0
> ```
>
> The period that each bw entry is being averaged over is not
> necessarily known and if an entry is being averaged over time other
> than a second the "average of averages" won't be per second either. I
> wonder if that (  KiB/s) is actually misleading...

Here's an even more egregious example from my own testing:

```
512M: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=15001: Sun Sep  6 22:45:26 2020
  write: IOPS=0, BW=153MiB/s (161MB/s)(45.0GiB/301044msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (msec): min=103, max=4290, avg=2819.80, stdev=988.46
    clat (msec): min=11, max=13196, avg=9817.42, stdev=1824.07
     lat (msec): min=2825, max=17272, avg=13162.17, stdev=1957.18
    clat percentiles (msec):
     |  1.00th=[   12],  5.00th=[ 8020], 10.00th=[ 8087], 20.00th=[ 8658],
     | 30.00th=[ 9060], 40.00th=[ 9597], 50.00th=[10134], 60.00th=[10268],
     | 70.00th=[10671], 80.00th=[10939], 90.00th=[11610], 95.00th=[12147],
     | 99.00th=[13221], 99.50th=[13221], 99.90th=[13221], 99.95th=[13221],
     | 99.99th=[13221]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=1046483, max=1048576, per=100.00%, avg=1048454.31, stdev=492.65, samples=86
   iops        : min=    1, max=    2, avg= 1.94, stdev= 0.24, samples=86
  lat (msec)   : 20=1.11%
  cpu          : usr=3.17%, sys=2.22%, ctx=185445, majf=0, minf=21
  IO depths    : 1=1.1%, 2=2.2%, 4=96.7%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,90,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=4

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=153MiB/s (161MB/s), 153MiB/s-153MiB/s (161MB/s-161MB/s), io=45.0GiB (48.3GB), run=301044-301044msec
```

where the average speed over the entire run is shown as 153 MiB/s, but the bw is sampled at 1024 MiB/s (iiuc).

Comment: That does indeed look unusual (e.g. the sampled iops). Were you using some abnormally big blocksize (e.g. bigger than what the kernel is sending down to disk as reported by iostat while the job is running)? If so that's going to cause all manner of distortions as kernel block splitting is opaque to fio.

Comment: Hi @Anon.  Aye, I've done some more testing of fio and it seems that in some places it counts ios as blocks and in other places, it counts the kernel-split blocks.  Applying some corrective arithmetic makes the numbers balance out in the end.  And, as Sitsofe explains, there are some numbers that are sampled that won't make sense for very large blocks (the "egregious" test was blocksize=512MiB)

Comment: Fio itself will count it's own "blocksize" for its internal data (everything down to and including "Run status"). The "Disk stats" (as included in your original question) are from the **kernel**'s statistics (where the I/O may have been transformed by merging/splitting). Out the Disk stats the other place you were thinking of?

Comment: Sorry, Anon.  Yes, I think you're right.